# Flask Socketio page needs to be refreshed everytime in order to emit message

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, socket.io, flask-socketio

So I had a  Python socketio script that logs onto a website does some processing and then stores the result onto a variable.This selenium process is defined in a function that is triggered when the user clicks on a button from the front end.A short snippet of what I have done is posted below:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_socketio import SocketIO

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'
socketio = SocketIO(app)

def selenium_process(data):
    (Some process that involves selenium)
    values = stores the result
    ..
    ..
    ..
    return values


@socketio.on('message')
def handle_message(message):
    dataval = selenium_process(data)
    socketio.emit('showresult',dataval)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app,host='my_ip',port=random_port)
```

This is the sample of  html + js file which is acting as client:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js'></script>
        <script src='http://localhost:3001/socket.io/socket.io.js'></script>
        <script>
        <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
            var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3001');
            function myFunction() 
            {
                data = {}
                socket.emit('message',data);
            }
            socket.on('showresult') {
                console.log(data);
            });
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```

The code is working fine although,result from the python server in only emitted once back to the js client when selenium process is done.After that I need to manually refresh the webpage and then emit to get the message on the front end.
What error am i making?

**EDIT:**
The process:
- I hit the 'Click me' button on the js client,which invokes the selenium process on the python server side.
- There's a bit of processing going on which invovles logging onto a website and fetching data along with pagination.
-The result is stored in a variable and then the server emits this result back to the client.
- On the client side,result is displayed on the console.
- So this happens only once , If I were to hit the 'Click me' button once again without refresh,again the process would be initiated, data will be fetched and stored in a varible but this time the 'emit' function won't work for some reason.

So my question was , will emit work more than once(after the function returns the data) even if I don't refresh the page?

Comment: You said "result from the python server in only emitted once back to the js client when selenium process is done". When did you expect the result to be sent? The selenium_process function is blocking, the emit will happen once that function returns, so I don't see what's wrong.

Comment: The client invokes the selenium process on the server side,once the process is done the server emits back the result data back to the client,but this only happens once.The next time the client invokes the selenium process ,the process works same as before but  server does not emit the data back to the client.I need to refresh the page manually and then emit for things to work proper

Comment: Kindly see the Edit I have made to the question.

Comment: You may want to check Socket.IO logs on the server and client sides to see where is this second emit getting lost. Check the documentations for the server and client for how to enable logs.

Comment: I did enable logs and found out that client is getting disconnected after a particular time,so some of the 'test' emits are getting lost.